# Create a table with columns from rows values with dynamic values

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with 'properties'

```
ID    Text
-----------
1     Name
2     Surname
3     D.O.B.
4     City
```

Another table with 'people'

```
ID    Code
-----------
1     MN0001
2     ST0001
3     ST0002
```

And another table 'propertiesPeople' that associate that 2 tables. A person can have an undefined quantity of properties.

```
ID    IDPerson    IDProp    Value
----------------------------------
1     1           1         Peter
2     1           2         Johnson
3     2           1         John
4     2           3         01/01/1977
5     1           4         California
6     3           1         Julian
7     3           2         Ross
8     3           4         Osaka
```

Before inserting a person/people, I need to validate that there is no other one with the same properties (the properties to validate is variable and it will be stored on another table 'propertiesToValidate')

I thought of making a dynamic SQL making a loop around the 'propertiesToValidate' and this Select would finish something like:

```
SELECT p1.Value, p2.Value, p3.Value
FROM properties p1
INNER JOIN properties p2 ON p1.IDPerson=p2.IDPerson
INNER JOIN properties p3 ON p1.IDPerson=p3.IDPerson
WHERE p1.IDProp = 1
AND p2.IDProp = 2
AND p3.IDProp = 4
```

And insert this into a temporal table that would finish something like this:

```
Value1     Value2    Value3
--------------------------------
Peter      Johnson   California
Julian     Ross      Osaka
```

After that, I would make an intersect with a table with the new person/people that I want to insert.

I think that creating a dynamic string and calling after with sp_executesql is not an elegant way to do it (and complicated to mantain in the future), but I can't realise another way to do it. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

I would just add `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE #propertiesPeople(
   ID       VARCHAR(34) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,IDPerson INTEGER 
  ,IDProp   INTEGER 
  ,Value    VARCHAR(10)
  ,UNIQUE(IDPerson, IDProp)
);
INSERT INTO #propertiesPeople(ID,IDPerson,IDProp,Value) VALUES ('1',1,1,'Peter');
INSERT INTO #propertiesPeople(ID,IDPerson,IDProp,Value) VALUES ('2',1,2,'Johnson');
INSERT INTO #propertiesPeople(ID,IDPerson,IDProp,Value) VALUES ('3',2,1,'John');
INSERT INTO #propertiesPeople(ID,IDPerson,IDProp,Value) VALUES ('4',2,3,'01/01/1977');
INSERT INTO #propertiesPeople(ID,IDPerson,IDProp,Value) VALUES ('5',1,4,'California');
INSERT INTO #propertiesPeople(ID,IDPerson,IDProp,Value) VALUES ('6',3,1,'Julian');
INSERT INTO #propertiesPeople(ID,IDPerson,IDProp,Value) VALUES ('7',3,2,'Ross');
INSERT INTO #propertiesPeople(ID,IDPerson,IDProp,Value) VALUES ('8',3,4,'Osaka');
```

When someone try to insert:

```
INSERT INTO #propertiesPeople(ID,IDPerson,IDProp,Value) VALUES ('9',3,4,'Osaka2');
```

Will get:

> **Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint** 'UQ__#propert__918436F84D776654'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.#propertiesPeople'. The
>   duplicate key value is (3, 4).

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/376969)**</kbd>

Comment: The person would be a new one. I want to not allow to create a new person that would create for example 3 new rows: 
    9,4,1 'Peter' ||||
    9,4,2, Johnson ||||
    9,4,4,'California'.
The number and value of the properties to validate depends on another table.

Comment: @popiandro So share example of this another table then

Comment: This table will just have the IDs of the Properties to validate (well, it will have more columns but is not important for the question)